# Relation in set of data (python, pandas)

Tags: pandas, statistics

I am trying to find a relation in a set of data (a table) with the first column is the given information and the rest of the columns is generated, for example:

```
row1 = [y11, x11, x12, x13 ...]
row2 = [y12, x21, x22, x23 ...]
```

etc.

All of the rows are known except for the `x`'s in the last row, so based on the rows above it is required to find the relation and obtain the last `x`'s.

Is it possible to achieve this with pandas methods?

Comment: What is the expected output? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: the output is the x values in the last row, given only the y value in that raw and based on the experience learned from the rows above the last row